Details move separate
I want to set pose to my character. He has some details on his head and neck, its separate object that I joined to body. When I rotate neck bones this details move separate. How to let this details move like part of the body?

How to smooth their deformation?

blend file:


Their vertices are not assigned to any vertex group, first thing activate the On Cage and Edit Mode options of the Armature modifier, select these vertices, at last select one vertex that is not too far and that moves correctly, open the N panel > Vertex Weights > click on Copy:

